# 'T' does not contain a definition

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to do the following (If so I can't seem to get it working.. forgoing constraints for the moment)...

If the type (because it's ommitted) is inferred, what's the problem?

```
private void GetGenericTableContent<T>(ref StringBuilder outputTableContent, T item)
{
    outputTableContent.Append("<td>" + item.SpreadsheetLineNumbers + "</td>");
}

// 'item' is either DuplicateSpreadsheetRowModel class or SpreadsheetRowModel class
```

With the above code I get the following error:

> 'T' does not contain a definition for 'SpreadsheetLineNumbers' and no extension method 'SpreadsheetLineNumbers' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to add constraint on you generic method, because currently T is of type object and object `does not contain a definition for 'SpreadsheetLineNumbers' `. If DuplicateSpreadsheetRowModel class or SpreadsheetRowModel descend from a common base class of implement the same interface use that as constraint.

Comment: C# generics aren’t implicitly typed. The way your method signature is written, it should be callable as `GetGenericTableContent(someStringBuilder, 42)`, with `T = int`. Obviously this would fail because `int` doesn’t have a member `SpreadsheetLineNumbers` so C# rightly rejects your code. That’s the whole point of constraints.

Comment: Ah, it seems I mistakenly thought that by ommitting the type it was inferred at compile time, which is what MS says "The compiler can infer the type parameters based on the method arguments you pass in; it cannot infer the type parameters only from a constraint or return value." and "the compiler includes only those generic methods on which type inference succeeded." ... so I guess which types does it succeed with... hmm... if it worked I would then add constraints.

Comment: The compiler does infer the type of generic arguments at each call site, the problem is your `GetGenericTableContent` method claims to work for any type `T` when it can only work for types with an appropriate `SpreadsheetLineNumbers` property. The way to describe such a type is to add a base class or interface constraint to `T` for some type which defines the required members.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No. Generic types must be known at compile time.
Think about it for a minute, how could compiler know that it is guaranteed that type `T` has specific property, namely `SpreadsheetLineNumbers`? What if `T` is of primitive type such as `int` or `object` ?

What prevents us from calling the method like this:  `GetGenericTableContent(ref _, 999)` with T as int here  ?

To fix it you could first add an interface that contains the property :

```
public interface MyInterface 
{
    string SpreadsheetLineNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

And let your class inherit from this interface:

```
public class MyClass : MyInterface
{
    public string SpreadsheetLineNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

Then we use generic type constraints to let compiler know that the type `T` derives from this interface and therefore it *has to* contain and implement all its members:

```
private void GetGenericTableContent<T>(ref StringBuilder outputTableContent, T item) 
    where T : IMyInterface // now compiler knows that type T has implemented SpreadsheetLineNumbers
{
    outputTableContent.Append("<td>" + item.SpreadsheetLineNumbers + "</td>");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you can't get make an interface for your type (or a common one between several types):

```
private void GetGenericTableContant<T>(ref StringBuilder outputTableContent, T item, Func<T, string> lineNumberAccessor)
{
     outputTableContent.Append("<td>" + lineNumberAccessor(item) + "</td>");
}
```

Usage:

```
GetGenericTableContent(ref outputTableContent, item, x => x.SpreadsheetLineNumbers);
```

*(Or you could just pass the SpreadSheetLineNumbers property if you don't really need the item reference in your method: `void GetGenericTableContant<T>(ref StringBuilder outputTableContent, string lineNumbers)`)*

Answer (score 3):

Actually it is possible if you know **for sure** that the generic T has the exact property, using the [where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) (generic type constraint) for a specified class with `where T : MyClass`.

---

For instance, if you have two entities `Foo` and `Boo`:

```
class Foo 
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime CreateDate {get; set;}
    public int FooProp {get; set;}
}

class Boo 
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime CreateDate {get; set;}
    public int BooProp {get; set;}
}
```

With a little refactor we can create a `BaseClass` that will hold the common properties:

```
class BaseModel
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime CreateDate {get; set;}        
}
```

And modify `Foo` and `Boo` to be:

```
class Boo : BaseModel
{
    public int BooProp {get; set;}
}

class Foo : BaseModel
{
    public int FooProp {get; set;}
}
```

And If you have a generic service with the constraint type of `where T : BaseModel` the compiler will allow you to get or set the `BaseModel`'s properties.

Lets say that you want that for every entity (`Foo` or `Boo`) added to DB you will want to set the `CreateDate` and `Id` properties from code (and not from server default value):

```
public interface IGenericService<T>
{
    void Insert(T obj);
}

public class GenericService<T> : IGenericService<T> where T : BaseModel
{
    public void Insert(T obj)
    {
        obj.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        obj.CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        this._repository.Insert(obj);           
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work with a generic type you must have a generic type constraint as either a common base class or interface declaring the `SpreadsheetLineNumbers` property.

However, I do not see an advantage in making this methods generic. You can as well type the parameter as this common base class or interface.

```cs
private void GetGenericTableContent(StringBuilder outputTableContent,
                                    SpreadsheetRowModelBase item)
{
    outputTableContent.Append("<td>" + item.SpreadsheetLineNumbers + "</td>");
}
```

If `DuplicateSpreadsheetRowModel` derives from `SpreadsheetRowModel`, you can simply type the parameter as `SpreadsheetRowModel`.

---

Also, `StringBuilder` is a class, i.e. a reference type. Therefore the `ref` keyword is not required because a reference is passed anyway. (With the `ref` keyword a reference to the reference would be passed, which makes only sense if you want to replace the existing `StringBuilder` by a new one in the method and want to reflect this change at the caller site.