# C# collection nested Node type (GTC issue)

Tags: c#, .net, oop, generics

**resolved: ** for anyone struggling to reference specific fields of a generic class/struct Type in a class or method *see the resolution* to [this problem:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659145/t-does-not-contain-a-definition) ['T' does not contain a definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659145/t-does-not-contain-a-definition)

I am currently trying to self-implement a binary search Tree (BST) structure - it is part of an assignment to do so to achieve an objective to facilitate Huffman encoding/decoding.

**edit: (relevant for question context)** a huffman Binary Search Tree needs 2 values stored inside of each of it's Nodes - a nullable char which can be set for 'leaf' Nodes only and a value by which to sort each Node.

I'd really like to be able to make my Tree accept a **generic Node type** within my current implementation, with an ***also generic*** type being given to the ***generic Node*** (a tongue twister for sure). The code is the best explanation:

```
    public class Node<T>
{
    //not required for some reason
    T Value;

    //pointers to left and right 'sub Nodes'
    public Node<T> LeftChild = null;

    public Node<T> RightChild = null;

    //pointer to Node's parent to allow bottom-up traversal if required
    public Node<T> Par = null;

    //to instantiate Node instances for Tree
    public Node()
    {
    }
}
```

An initial part of the BST's code (to show Generic type constraints (GTCs)):

```
public class Tree<T, TNode> 
    where TNode : Node<T>, new()
    where T : IComparable
{
    private TNode root = null;

    //return the topmost Node of the Tree instance
    public TNode GetRoot()
    {
        return root;
    }
......
}
```

The issue only arises from the fact that **TNode derives from Node**, but has LeftChild/RightChild field members which are of **the same Type**.

For the C# compiler this is an error, and wherever .RightChild, .LeftChild or .Par is implemented in my BST methods an error is thrown. Is there a workaround or obvious GTC solution at all?

Comment: When you write to people who you don't know, and who have various backgrounds and experiences, remember to not use acronyms unless you spell them out at least once. I recommend spelling out BST and GTC so you increase your chance of getting good answers. Also I think you need to add the `TNode` class to your question.

Comment: The code in the question does not give any compiler error. Furthermore, your problem/error description is so vague and unspecific, it pretty much is impossible to understand... :( That said, why would you need TNode at all? Just use Node<T>...

Comment: Racil- there is no TNode class - it’s a generic Type as it’s given as a generic Type argument of Tree. As specified by Generic Type Constraints it has to be derived from the original Node<T> class

Comment: Elgonzo - I didn’t add the methods which were causing the compiler issue - possibly an oversight, but any reference in Tree to ‘<TNode<T>>.LeftChild’, <TNode<T>>.‘RightChild’ or ‘<TNode<T>>.Par’ is the issue - the compiler has detected these fields in the base class and wants a cast from Node<T> to the generic type TNode<T>

Comment: I am sorry, but you are still making only little sense. I guess when you talk about `TNode<T>`, you really mean `TNode` (without the generic qualifier `<T>`), according to the code in your question. Since `LeftChild`, `RightChild` and `Par` are fields of `Node<T>`, and `TNode` according to the constraint in your Tree class **must be** derived from `Node<T>`, the compiler will have no problem accessing those fields. Sure, the fields are of type `Node<T>` and not of type `TNode` (which is a generic parameter of a type that is unknown during compile time). (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Which leads me to the question/suggestion: Why do you have a TNode type in your Tree class at all? Just don't use it. Use Node<T> directly instead of TNode...

Comment: Thankyou for bearing with me  - the reason I wanted to be able to implement a generic 'TNode' class derived from Node in my Tree is so that I could keep my original Tree structure intact at all times (*not have to change it for other projects/implementations*) and simply extend Node to have other relevant fields for the objective of different scenarios. This is as opposed to writing a custom class to use as T in Node<T> where I could additional fields, as this would be more decorators (and ugliness)

Comment: Since `T` is already the same generic type parameter for `Tree<T>` as well as `Node<T>`, your generic `Tree<T>` class would not need to change anyway. (Think about it, your current Tree<T, TNode> is already dependent on Node<T>, because Node<T> is a constraint for TNode.) If you want to be more independent with regard to different node implementations, create an `ITreeNode<T>` interface (with properties instead of fields), and let Tree<T> use this interface ITreeNode<T>. Depending on whatever needs/projects, different concrete node types implementing ITreeNode<T> could be created...

Comment: Thankyou - that makes sense - as a new-ish beginner to OO it is sometimes difficult to wrap my head around solving problems without inheritance so have been encountering problems a fair bit!